# Cannot set initialValues on SelectField component using redux-form-material-ui

Tags: reactjs, redux, redux-form

I am trying to render initialValues for a form using redux-form-material-ui. So far initialValues are working for my TextField components but not for SelectField.

I am currently passing initialValues as a prop through the parent component like this:

```
    <PacketFilterForm initialValues={this.props.initialConfigValuesForForm} />
```

This is working on this case:

```
     <Field name="name" component={TextField} hintText="Ex. Rule 1" floatingLabelText='Name of Rule'/>
```

However, it is not working for this case:

```
     <Field component={SelectField} name='ethertype'>
          <MenuItem key={1} value='ipv4' primaryText="IPV4" />,
          <MenuItem key={2} value='ipv6' primaryText="IPV6" />
     </Field>
```

How can I set an initialValues for this SelectField component?

Answer (score 0):

try in your `componentWillMount()` because `Form` component of `redux form` works with name and value

```
componentWillMount() {
    this.props.change('ethertype', 'ipv6')
}
```